Mystery sockets named "of component" & "for component" when using the UrSPahoMqttClient extension in MIT App Inventor
When using the Block Editor in the MIT App Inventor website for the imported UrSPahoMqttClient extension, for each of the purple and green code blocks that are available for drag and drop into the Block Editor, there are mystery empty socket named "of component" and "for component".
These empty sockets appear to possibly be a newer addition for this extension.
The website for this extension fails to show these empty sockets in the block examples it provides. The website address for the UrSPahoMqttClient extension is:
Blockquote
https://ullisroboterseite.de/android-AI2-MQTT-en.html#use
An image of code blocks follows:


Looks like you are using the AnyComponent versions of the blocks. Don't. Find the extension in the palette on the left and select the blocks from there, not from the AnyComponent blocks.

@MetricRat you should write this as answer...

Looks like you are using the AnyComponent versions of the blocks. Don't. Find the extension in the palette on the left and select the blocks from there, not from the AnyComponent blocks.

While it is true that these code blocks are selected from AnyComponent blocks, the reason why they are selected from AnyComponent blocks is because the option to select from the extension by way of the normal flyout selection does NOT work.     Unlikely any of the other components w/in Screen1 which have flyout menus that allow for selecting various code blocks ,  this imported extension, UrsPahoMqttClient,  has flyout menus that will NOT expand and display the code blocks that are available.   Only after closing all the Screen1 features and opening AnyComponents, are flyout menus visible.

I have just tested the extension (version 1.9) in a new project, and have no issue selecting the blocks (non AnyComponent)

The extension I imported is Extension Version: 1.0
Date Built: 2020-11-15.   I'm not sure how I determined the version used in this sketch.  It seems you have found a newer version of the extension.  I will give you the credit for answering this question.  Thanks for the great solution to this question.
